# PHP mysqli query issue when running multiple queries inside while loops

Tags: php, mysqli

I have the following php code:

```
if($getPrepareResults = $con->prepare("SELECT machinePurposeID 
                                       FROM machinepurpose 
                                       WHERE machinePurposeName LIKE '%$needle%' 
                                       AND machinePurposePerms=1")) {
    $getPrepareResults->execute();
    $getPrepareResults->store_result();
    if($getPrepareResults->num_rows > 0) {
        $found = true;
        $getPrepareResults->bind_result($machinePurposeID);
        while($getPrepareResults->fetch()) {
            if($getMachineID = $con->prepare("SELECT machineID 
                                             FROM machinedetails 
                                             WHERE machinePurpose=?")) 
              {
                $getMachineID->bind_param("i", $machinePurposeID);
                $getMachineID->execute();
                $getMachineID->bind_result($machineID);
                while($getMachineID->fetch()) {
                    if($getMachine = $con->prepare("SELECT 
                                            machineID,machineIP,
                                            machineName,hostID 
                                           FROM machines 
                                           WHERE machineID=?")) {
                        $getMachine->bind_param("i", $machineID);
                        $getMachine->execute();
                        $getMachine->bind_result($machineID,$machineIP,
                                                 $machineName,$hostID);
                        while($getMachine->fetch()) {

                        };
                    };
                    $getMachine->close();
                };
            };
            $getMachineID->close();
        };
    } else {
        $found = false;
    };
};
$getPrepareResults->close();
```

For some reason it works up to the point of `getMachineID` and then for some reason it produces an error when I attempt to `getMachine`. I guess it is because I am attempting to run too many queries one after another.

What would be the best way to get the same result as would currently be output, with no errors, but differently?

**All Table names and Column Names are correct.**

**Note: this is an internal web server, so I don't have to worry about SQL Injection**

Edit:

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLfAB.png), More information in Comments:

Comment: `"it produces an error"` - And what is the error?  Errors shouldn't be ignored, they exist to tell you about the problem.  `"I guess it is because I am attempting to run too many queries one after another"` - What makes you think that?  Databases are pretty good at executing database queries.  It may not be the most efficient approach, but I doubt the database is annoyed by it or refusing to cooperate.  `"I don't have to worry about SQL Injection"` - Yes you do.

Comment: @David - how does one inject a server that isn't connected to the internet? the `error`, I have added a screenshot of the _firefox inspector_ as I am using `ajax` to contact the page. I tested running one query, then 2 and then 3, it only seems to stop working when i added the third query.

Comment: Use to avoid error in page by `error_reporting(E_all);` or `error_reporting(0);`

Comment: @user4985641: SQL injection isn't always intentional or malicious, and isn't always from public/unknown users.  And ignoring it is a famously bad habit.  As for the error, an "internal server error" usually means that there was an error... on the server... internally.  Check your PHP logs, turn on error reporting, etc.  We can't debug your server for you.  Don't treat your code like a black box, actually debug it.

Comment: `....while($getMachine->fetch()) { };`... Is there any code inside this loop?

Comment: I think you missed to call `$getMachineID->store_result();` before the inner while loop.

Comment: @KirsSudh What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: @AbcAeffchen, I only stored the results in the first loop to check if the `like machinePurposeName` was valid, after that I shouldn't have to check if things are valid as they are all ran by _foreign keys_

Comment: storing the result, frees the connection for a new query. If you have an open statement, it results sometimes in an out of sync error (or something like that. Just give it a try.

Comment: Try to debug by printing just before `while($getMachineID->fetch()) {` without looping.

Comment: @AbcAeffchen, Nice! Feel free to submit an answer, it seems to of worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Short answer

You missed to add `$getMachineID->store_result();` before the inner while loop.

#### Background

If you make a query (using a regular query or via a prepared statement), a statement is returned that blocks your database connection until all results are fetched, or the whole result set is stored, or the statement is closed.

So if you want to make nested queries, you have to either fetch all results saving them in an array or something and close the statement, or use `store_result()`.

You have to call `store_result()`, if you want to use the `affected_rows` property of the statement. But you have to call it also, if you are fetching e.g. data from a `LONGTEXT` field, since it can contain up to 4 GB of text. If you just call `fetch()`, it results (without changing the PHP settings) in an allocation error, because PHP tries to allocate 4 GB of memory to be sure that it can fetch the whole string.

#### Improvements?

Maybe you can get rid of the inner while loop by using a `JOIN`. Something like

```
SELECT
  machineID, machineIP, machineName, hostID 
FROM
  machines
  JOIN machinedetails USING(machineID)
WHERE
  machinePurpose = ?
```

This would reduce the number of queries and should improve the performance and also solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that `store_resut()` worked like that. I generally used it for when I had to check to see if rows existed or not.

Comment: @user4985641 You are welcome. I added one more detail to `store_result` and a suggestion for an improvement.